# controladores de video html5

Tags: vídeo

Tenho em meu código um vídeo que foi colocado com as seguintes tags:

```
 <div id="video">
       <img src="images/bg-video.png" id="bg-video">
            <video  width="100%" height="100%" loop>
            <source src="video/animacao-lol.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
       </video>
 </div>
```

porem assim que a pagina carrega o vídeo começa a rodar com som auto porem não quero usar os controles que já vem disponível na tag vídeo quero estilizar o meu vídeo com meus próprios controladores que seria o Play e o volume e também queria que meu vídeo começasse "mutado" para não assustar o usuário quando ele entrar na pagina  segue a imagem de como queria que ficasse meus controladores :

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E assim mais ou menos que teria que ficar  com o botão de play quando eu clicar nele aparecer o de pause e assim por diante se for possível fazer isso por favor me ajudem.

código que estou usando:

tag de video:

```
<div id="video">
           <img src="images/bg-video.png" id="bg-video">
                <video  width="100%" height="100%" loop>
                <source src="video/animacao-lol.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
           </video>
     </div>
```

js do vídeo

```
function init() {        // Master function, encapsulates all functions
        var video = document.getElementById("Video1");                                               
        if (video.canPlayType) {   // tests that we have HTML5 video support
            // if successful, display buttons and set up events
            document.getElementById("buttonbar").style.display = "block";                
            document.getElementById("inputField").style.display = "block";

            // helper functions
            //  play video
            function vidplay(evt) {
                if (video.src == "") {  // inital source load
                    getVideo();
                }
                button = evt.target; //  get the button id to swap the text based on the state                                    
                if (video.paused) {   // play the file, and display pause symbol
                    video.play();
                    button.textContent = "||";
                } else {              // pause the file, and display play symbol  
                    video.pause();
                    button.textContent = ">";
                }
            }
            //  load video file from input field
            function getVideo() {
                var fileURL = document.getElementById("videoFile").value;  // get input field                    
                if (fileURL != "") {
                    video.src = fileURL;
                    video.load();  // if HTML source element is used
                    document.getElementById("play").click();  // start play
                } else {
                    errMessage("Enter a valid video URL");  // fail silently
                }
            }



            //  button helper functions 
            //  skip forward, backward, or restart
            function setTime(tValue) {
            //  if no video is loaded, this throws an exception 
                try {
                    if (tValue == 0) {
                        video.currentTime = tValue;
                    }
                    else {
                        video.currentTime += tValue;
                    }

                 } catch (err) {
                     // errMessage(err) // show exception
                 errMessage("Video content might not be loaded");
                   }
         }
            //  display an error message 
            function errMessage(msg) {
            // displays an error message for 5 seconds then clears it
                document.getElementById("errorMsg").textContent = msg;
                setTimeout("document.getElementById('errorMsg').textContent=''", 5000);
            }
            // change volume based on incoming value 
            function setVol(value) {
                var vol = video.volume;
                vol += value;
                //  test for range 0 - 1 to avoid exceptions
                if (vol >= 0 && vol <= 1) {
                    // if valid value, use it
                    video.volume = vol;
                } else {
                    // otherwise substitute a 0 or 1
                    video.volume = (vol < 0) ? 0 : 1;                        
                }
            }
            //  button events               
            //  Play
            document.getElementById("play").addEventListener("click", vidplay, false);
            //  Restart
            document.getElementById("restart").addEventListener("click", function () {
                setTime(0);
            }, false);
            //  Skip backward 10 seconds
            document.getElementById("rew").addEventListener("click", function () {
                setTime(-10);
            }, false);
            //  Skip forward 10 seconds
            document.getElementById("fwd").addEventListener("click", function () {
                setTime(10);
            }, false);
            //  set src == latest video file URL
            document.getElementById("loadVideo").addEventListener("click", getVideo, false);

            // fail with message 
            video.addEventListener("error", function (err) {
                errMessage(err);
            }, true);
            // volume buttons
            document.getElementById("volDn").addEventListener("click", function () {
                setVol(-.1); // down by 10%
            }, false);
            document.getElementById("volUp").addEventListener("click", function () {
                setVol(.1);  // up by 10%
            }, false);

            // playback speed buttons
            document.getElementById("slower").addEventListener("click", function () {
                video.playbackRate -= .25;
            }, false);
            document.getElementById("faster").addEventListener("click", function () {
                video.playbackRate += .25;
            }, false);
            document.getElementById("normal").addEventListener("click", function () {
                video.playbackRate = 1;
            }, false);
            document.getElementById("mute").addEventListener("click", function (evt) {
                if (video.muted) {
                    video.muted = false;
                    evt.target.innerHTML = "<img alt='volume on button' src='vol2.png' />"
                } else {
                    video.muted = true;
                    evt.target.innerHTML = "<img alt='volume off button' src='mute2.png' />"
                }
            }, false);
        } // end of runtime
    }// end of master
```

esse cádigo não funciona porque peguei ele de exemplo porem não esta funcionando

Comment: chegou a procurar no google? Só na primeira página da consulta tem uns 6 tutoriais... http://lmgtfy.com/?q=html5+video+custom+controls

Comment: sim porem nao deu certo

Comment: ótimo então assim, reformula tua pergunta dessa forma: Posta os códigos que tu tentou(já fez, mas acredito que tenha mais), diz que tu seguiu o tutorial Y (passa o link) e que na parte de implementar X ela não funcionou. Com a tua pergunta formulada dessa forma vai ser muito mais fácil você conseguir respostas boas, pois a pergunta vai estar bem formulada!

Comment: Pronto amigo esta editada

Answer (score 2):

Não consigo apagar a minha pergunta porem eu consegui fazer oque eu queria
vou deixar isso como resposta pára se alguém algum dia precisar vai ter aqui:

o HTML:

```
            <h1 class="nomes">Lorem ipsum <strong class="slidText">Dolor</strong></h1>
            <p class="texto1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed at risus neque. <br>Cras sit amet ligula 
                ut justo commodo porta id ut enim. Nulla est lectus, mollis sit amet vehicula id, volutpat eget mauris.</p>


            <div id="buttonbar" style="display: none;">

                <button id="play" title="Play button"></button>
                <button id="volDn"  title="Volume down button">-</button>
                <button id="volUp"  title="Volume up button">+</button>
                <button id="mute" title="Mute button" ><img src="images/video/demultado.png"/></button>        
            </div>   

            <center>
                <ul class="actions">
                    <li><a href="#one" class="botao-circulo scrolly"><img src="images/seta-baixo.png"></a></li>
                </ul>
            </center>
        </div>
    </section>
```

o js:

```
function init() {        // Master function, encapsulates all functions
    var video = document.getElementById("Video1");
    if (video.canPlayType) {   // tests that we have HTML5 video support
        // if successful, display buttons and set up events
        document.getElementById("buttonbar").style.display = "block";



        //  play video
        function vidplay(evt) {
            if (video.src == "") {  // inital source load
                getVideo();
            }
            button = evt.target; //  get the button id to swap the text based on the state                                    
            if (video.paused) {   // play the file, and display pause symbol
                video.play();
                button.textContent = "||";
            } else {              // pause the file, and display play symbol  
                video.pause();
                button.textContent = ">";
            }
        }



        // change volume based on incoming value 
        function setVol(value) {
            var vol = video.volume;
            vol += value;
            //  test for range 0 - 1 to avoid exceptions
            if (vol >= 0 && vol <= 1) {
                // if valid value, use it
                video.volume = vol;
            } else {
                // otherwise substitute a 0 or 1
                video.volume = (vol < 0) ? 0 : 1;
            }
        }


        //  button events               
        //  Play


        document.getElementById("play").addEventListener("click", vidplay, false);

        // volume buttons
        document.getElementById("volDn").addEventListener("click", function () {
            setVol(-.1); // down by 10%
        }, false);
        document.getElementById("volUp").addEventListener("click", function () {
            setVol(.1);  // up by 10%
        }, false);


        document.getElementById("mute").addEventListener("click", function (evt) {
            if (video.muted) {
                video.muted = false;
                evt.target.innerHTML = "<img alt='volume on button' src='../images/video/mutado.png' id='js-imagem' />"
            } else {
                video.muted = true;
                evt.target.innerHTML = "<img alt='volume off button' src='../images/video/desmutado.png' />"
            }
        }, false);
    } // end of runtime
}// end of master
```